# BSON JSON id vs _id

Tags: mongodb, go

I am creating simple REST API using MongoDB and golang as a driver.
I was able to create POST request which can be found here:
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNDWv.png).

However, when creating GET request, i always need to get it by bson _id. Would someone be able to let me know how to retrieve from json id not bson _id from golang script. If this is not possible, I would appreciate if someone let me know how to convert id to _id.

models/user.go

```
package models

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type User struct {
    Id     bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson: "_id"`
    Name   string        `json:"name" bson: "name"`
    Gender string        `json:"gender" bson: "gender"`
    Age    int           `json:"age" bson: "age"`
}
```

controllers/user.go file

```
type UserController struct {
    session *mgo.Session}

func httpResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, jsonOut []byte, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", jsonOut)
}

func NewUserCOntroller(s *mgo.Session) *UserController {
    // return the address of UserController
    return &UserController{s}
}

func (uc UserController) GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    id := p.ByName("id")

    if !bson.IsObjectIdHex(id) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    }
    // oid is something you use in mongo
    oid := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
    u := models.User{}
    if err := uc.session.DB("mongolang").C("users").FindId(oid).One(&u); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        return
    }

    uj, err := json.Marshal(u)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    httpResponse(w, uj, http.StatusOK)

}

func (uc UserController) CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    // its empty for now
    u := models.User{}

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u)

    u.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
    uc.session.DB("mongolang").C("users").Insert(u)

    jsonOut, _ := json.Marshal(u)
    httpResponse(w, jsonOut, http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Println("Response:", string(jsonOut), " 201 OK")
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"

    "mongo-golang/controllers"
)

func main() {
    // create new instance
    r := httprouter.New()
    // new session
    uc := controllers.NewUserCOntroller(getSession())
    r.GET("/user/:id", uc.GetUser)
    r.POST("/user", uc.CreateUser)
    r.DELETE("/user/:id", uc.DeleteUser)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:9000", r)
}

func getSession() *mgo.Session {
    // get session and connect with mongo
    s, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would someone be able to let me know how to retrieve from json id not bson _id from golang script.

You can do that only if you save bson Id as a Hex string in the additional field in an object, but don't do that. That is unnecessary and you won't get anything.

> If this is not possible, I would appreciate if someone let me know how to convert id to _id.

There are two functions that converting bson ObjectID to string and string to bson ObjectID

for id to _id, you already use that function in your code:

```
oid := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
```

bson.ObjectIdHex() convert hex representation of objectID to bson.objectID. Hex representation is what you would see in JSON output.

After you invoke that function you get bson.ObjetID. There is a method .Hex() that can get you Hex (text/json) representation of that object.

```
oid := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
json_represenation_of_bson_object_id = oid.Hex()
```

Also, you use the old mongo driver, a new driver written and maintained by MongoDB is what you should use:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver